# displaying error validation message in angularjs php

Tags: php, angularjs

At the backend, am checking to ensure that php variable userid is not empty and that name variable is the same otherwise let it return error message. My front view is in angularjs.

**The problem is that my data validation checking is not returning error message.**

I have implemented the validation check in angularjs as

```
if (response.data.trim() === 'data_empty') {

//show error msg
            $scope.errorMsg = true;
            //hide the msg after 5 secs
            $timeout(function(){
$scope.errorMsg = false;
//window.location = 'errorpage.php';
}, 5000);

}


if (response.data.trim() === 'name_not_the_same') {

//show error msg
            $scope.errorMsg2 = true;
            //hide the msg after 5 secs
            $timeout(function(){
$scope.errorMsg2 = false;
}, 5000);

}
```

**at html am having**

```
<div class="alert alert-danger" ng-show="errorMsg">
        <strong>Wrong!</strong> All Field Must be Filled.!.
    </div>


<div class="alert alert-danger" ng-show="errorMsg2">
        <strong>Wrong!</strong> Name must be the same.!.
    </div>
```

How do I validate the data and return messages in angularjs. below is the entire code

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>


        <title></title>
        <link href="style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <style>
            .comment{
                border-bottom: 1px solid gray;
                padding: 5px;
            }
        </style>

    </head>
    <body ng-app='myapp'>
        <div class="content" ng-controller='fetchCtrl' >

            <div class="post" ng-repeat='post in posts'>
                <h1 >{{ post.title }}</h1>
                <div class="post-text">
                    {{ post.content }}
                </div>

            </div>

        </div>



<div class="alert alert-danger" ng-show="errorMsg">
        <strong>Wrong!</strong> All Field Must be Filled.!.
    </div>


<div class="alert alert-danger" ng-show="errorMsg2">
        <strong>Wrong!</strong> Name must be the same.!.
    </div>

        <!-- Script -->
        <script src="angular.min.js"></script>
        <script>
        var fetch = angular.module('myapp', []);
        fetch.controller('fetchCtrl', ['$scope', '$http','$timeout', function ($scope, $http, $timeout) {

                // Fetch post data
                $scope.getPosts = function(){

                    $http({
                        method: 'post',
                        url: 'likeunlike.php',
                        data: {request: 1}
                    }).then(function successCallback(response) {

$scope.posts = response.data;



if (response.data.trim() === 'data_empty') {

//show error msg
            $scope.errorMsg = true;
            //hide the msg after 5 secs
            $timeout(function(){
$scope.errorMsg = false;
//window.location = 'errorpage.php';
}, 5000);

}


if (response.data.trim() === 'name_not_the_same') {

//show error msg
            $scope.errorMsg2 = true;
            //hide the msg after 5 secs
            $timeout(function(){
$scope.errorMsg2 = false;
}, 5000);

}


                    });

                }

                $scope.getPosts(); // Fetch post data

            }


        ]);

        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

**php**

```
<?php

include "config.php";

$data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));

$request = $data->request;
$userid = '';
$name ='tony';

if($userid !=''){
$response ='data_empty';
echo  $response;
exit();
}


if($name !='tony'){
$response1 ='name_not_the_same';
echo  $response1;
exit();
}




// Get all posts list and like unlike
if($request == 1){

    $response_arr = array();

    $query = "SELECT * FROM posts";
    $result = mysqli_query($con,$query);

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
        $postid = $row['id'];
        $title = $row['title'];
        $content = $row['content'];
        $type = -1;


        $response_arr[] = array("id" => $postid, "title" => $title);
    }

    echo json_encode($response_arr);
    exit;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you need to verify that the JSON parse worked first:

```
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));
if (json_last_error() !== JSON_ERROR_NONE) { 
  echo 'bad_json';
  exit();
}

// now safe to use $data
$request = $data->request;
...
```

Comment: The problem is not whether variable should be sent as request or hardcoded. I have tried both and it does not print any error via angularjs

Comment: So looking in your javascript console, what does `likeunlike.php` return?

Comment: angular.min.js:124 Error: [ngRepeat:dupes] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.6.6/ngRepeat/dupes?p0=post%20in%20posts&p1=string%3A%3C&p2=%3C
    at angular.min.js:7
    at angular.min.js:315
    at angular.min.js:147
    at m.$digest (angular.min.js:148)
    at m.$apply (angular.min.js:151)
    at l (angular.min.js:103)
    at s (angular.min.js:108)
    at XMLHttpRequest.y.onload (angular.min.js:109)

Comment: Are you using Chrome? Click on the Network tab and select the `likeunlike.php` request. What is the response?

Comment: Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\angle\comment\likeunlike.php on line 8

Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\angle\comment\likeunlike.php on line 9
name_not_the_same

Comment: Looks like you need to address those PHP errors. I'm guessing `$request = $data->request;` is the problem.